# "Open attachment with" macro in mutt email client

Tags: email, macros, mutt

Sometimes I receive email attachments whose mimetypes are not in my mailcap file. To open such attachments from mutt, I usually select the attachment from the list, hit `s` to save the file to `/tmp`, and then use **`!`** to open the saved file with whatever application suits, using a shell command.

Is it possible to automate this with a mutt macro, which simply saves the selected attachment to **`/tmp`**, queries for an application name,  and then opens the saved file with this application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will answer my own question. The following entry in `.muttrc` does what I want:

```
macro attach O \
"\
<enter-command>unset wait_key<enter>\
<shell-escape>rm -f /tmp/mutt-attach<enter>\
<save-entry><kill-line>/tmp/mutt-attach<enter>\
<shell-escape> /tmp/mutt-attach &^A\
"
```

Description (line by line):

- map the macro to the `O` key in attachment mode
- disable "Press any key to continue ..."
- remove the file `/tmp/mutt-attach` if it exists
- save the selected entry to `/tmp/mutt-attach`
- start a shell command, input `/tmp/mutt-attach &` and go to the beginning of the line (`^A`)

Then I can simply input the program I want to use and hit enter, which will open the selected attachment in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to always open the same program (firefox in my case):

```
macro attach F \
"\
<enter-command>unset wait_key<enter>\
<shell-escape>rm -f /tmp/mutt-attach<enter>\
<save-entry><kill-line>/tmp/mutt-attach<enter>\
<shell-escape>firefox /tmp/mutt-attach &<enter>\
"
```